# Backing up external drives

Tags: macos, backup, external-hard-drive, compression

I have a WD 320GB external drive and a WD 1TB external drive. I would like to backup my 320GB on a regular basis. I have tried using the built in compressor in mac, but that fails saying unable to compress a file. I have also tried many other mac compressors and had no success. What is the best way to backup my external drive? Just copy and past the files over? Or to use a programme? By the way, I am open to windows ideas as well.

Edit: I would like to back up my 320GB to my 1TB on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/)** would be my choice. You can select the 320GB external as the source and the 1TB external as the destination and save it for regular backup.

[image]

If you're not using an HFS+ drive and are thus not as concerned about OS X metadata, **[Synkron](http://synkron.sourceforge.net/)** is a good choice.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have downloaded it and it says I need HFS+ formatting for my 320GB. However, I don't want to format it in HFS+ because I use it college (Windows computers) and at home (Mac laptop). This would not allow me to use with with windows computers.

Comment: @hart1994: see my edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! This has helped me a lot and works great!